# C++11 lambda cannot access reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a problem with a lambda function in C++: I'm trying to define an asynchronous loader that fills an array of object given a list of string as input.

The code looks like this (not exactly, but I hope you get the idea):

```
void loadData() {
    while (we_have_data()) {
        std::string str = getNext();
        array.resize(array.size() + 1);
        element &e = array.back();
        tasks.push_back([&, str] () {
            std::istringstream iss(str);
            iss >> e;
        }
    }

    for (auto task: tasks) {
        task();
    }
}
```

When at the end I scan the list of tasks and execute them, the application crashes on the first access to the variable e inside the lambda. If I run inside a debugger, I can find the right values inside the object e itself. I am doing something wrong, but I don't really understand what.

Comment: is `array` a `std::vector` that undergoes relocation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two strikes against you here.

Firstly, you are capturing a reference to an iterator to a vector that is likely to be resized and thus relocated.

Secondly, you are capturing a reference to a local (stack) variable that goes out of scope. Within the loop, the compiler probably uses the same memory location for 'e' each time, so all of the references would point to the same stack location.

A simpler solution would be to store the element number:

```
while (we_have_data()) {
    std::string str = getNext();
    size_t e = array.size();
    array.resize(e + 1);
    tasks.push_back([&, e, str] () {
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        iss >> array[e];
    }
}
```

If you have C++14 and your strings are long, you may want to consider:

```
    tasks.push_back([&, e, str{std::move(str)}] () {
```

All of this assumes that array will not undergo further manipulations or go out of scope while the tasks are running.

Comment: `str{std::move(str)}` is C++14 ?

Comment: Assuming it's a `vector` (or standard container), the `.back()` provides a reference to the last element, not an iterator.

Comment: and a *local reference variable* is not captured

Comment: I think this is out of bounds: `array[e]`?

Comment: fixed the out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

You are holding a dangling reference.  When you do

```
tasks.push_back([&, str] () {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    iss >> e;
}
```

You capture by reference the element returned by `array.back()` since a reference to `e` is actually a reference to whatever `e` refers to.  Unfortunately `resize` is called in the while loop so when `array` is resized the references to `back()` are invalidated and you are now referring to an object that no longer exist.

Comment: `[&]` captures a reference to `array.back()`, not a reference to reference, I guess, and it becomes dangling when `array` is resized, I think

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yeah just noticed that.  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The scope of `element& e` is the `while`-loop.

After every iteration of the `while`-loop, you have lambda functions with a captured reference to different `e`'s, which have all gone out-of-scope.

Comment: Sniped by NathanOliver

Answer (score 2):

You capture `e` (aka. `array.back()`) "by-reference" when creating the lambda, with subsequent resizes of the `array` (with possible reallocations), leaves a dangling reference and in turn causes an error when you attempt to access this dangling reference. Any attempt (not limited to the lambda) to access elements in the `array` by a previously assigned reference after the array has undergone a resize (and reallocation) will cause a "dangling reference" problem.

An alternative... instead of the two loops, why not just execute the task immediately in the `while` loop and forgo the dangling reference and attempting to get pointer or iterator based alternatives working.

Further alternative... if the elements in the `array` can be shared, a `std::shared_ptr` solution could work, the caveat would be to capture the `shared_ptr` elements by value, thus ensuring the lambda shared shares ownership of those elements with the `array` as it is resized.

A sampling of the idea...

```
void loadData() {
    while (we_have_data()) {
        std::string str = getNext();
        array.resize(array.size() + 1);
        std::shared_ptr<element> e = array.back();
        tasks.push_back([e, str] () {
            std::istringstream iss(str);
            iss >> *e;
        }
    }

    for (auto task: tasks) {
        task();
    }
}
```